# Remove aspx extension from SharePoint pages

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I would like to remove the ".aspx" extension from pages in a SharePoint web application. This can be done with URL rewriting in IIS web applications, but I cannot find any way to achieve this is SharePoint site pages.

e.g. abcsite/pages/default.aspx should be abcsite/pages/default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which version of `sherepoint` you are using.

You can use `IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 module`

Please have a look at these example which has setp by step instructions

[IIS7 URL Rewrite module](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/)

[SharePoint 2010 with IIS URL Rewrite 2.0](http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/23/sharepoint-2010-with-iis-url-rewrite-20.html)

[URL Routing with ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Sharepoint but you can use [Url Routing with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as an alternative to IIS Rewrite Modules.

One advantage being that forms post back to the correct URL which I prefer (without having to reverse map using IIS Url Rewriting)

Note: Available from .NET 4.0